# How do I resolve samba share to IP address or host name

Tags: networking, samba

I have a list of hosts in the network providing shares via SAMBA. How can I determine either IP address or the host name of one particular host, e.g. the one with the name “SASAK02”.

The output of `smbtree` is as follows

```
WORKGROUP
    \\SASAK02               
    \\SAURA-PC1             
    \\PC-VAN-DAMME
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try `nmblookup <wins-hostname>`.

Comment: Example: `nmblookup -U WORKGROUP -R SASAK02`

Answer (score 1):

You can install wireshark and start a scan on your network card.

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark
gksu wireshark
```

start monitoring your network-device (usually `eth0`, `wlp1s0` or `wlan0`), filter the result by "nbns" and you will see the IP in the upper window.

If it doesn't show up, go to your filemanager in the network tab where you see the share and actualize the sceen (usually F5)

A simpler solution is `nmblookup` (part of `samba-common-bin`) but it doesn't find all shares, for example:

```
nmblookup saura-pc1
```

Comment: why the downvote? please explain.