# Get the IP for NetBios name

Tags: networking, netbios

There is a mashine called "BIE" visible in my network surrounding of my dolphin File manager (Ubuntu 14.10).

I cannot access that device in dolphin and also don't get an answer pinging it.

How can I find out the IP of that device to do an intense scan with nmap?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can install wireshark and start a scan on your network card.

Filter the result by "nbns" and you will see the IP in the upper window.

Comment: This is why tools like [nmblookup](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/nmblookup.1.html) exist and may be easier to use than wireshark.

Comment: I tried  `nmblookup` but it doesn't find all shares

Comment: because `nmblookup` is for resolving the hostname to an IP address. To list shares that host is providing you can use `smbclient`. `wireshark` likely wouldn't show you a full list of shares either unless you were already requesting it by some other means.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by example but `smbclient -L <server>` is what you'd use to enumerate the shares a server was providing. Syntax of the `nmblookup` command is posted in that other answer.

Comment: That's the problem: if you don't know the server, you cannot examine it with smbclient

Comment: If you know neither the server nor what share you're wanting to examine then I don't know if there's really a tool to help you short of using `nmap` or something to find servers listening on one of the SMB-related ports.

Comment: I only know the name "BIE" that shows up in my network. As I posted here in my answer: wireshark works perfectly well in this case.

Answer (score 4):

This is a duplicate of [How do I resolve samba share to IP address or host name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29930/how-do-i-resolve-samba-share-to-ip-address-or-host-name)

The solution there: `nmblookup <hostname>`
So: `nmblookup BIE`